# How to make curved picture animation with THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js

I want to make an image transition animation as in the input area of the sample site I have given below. But since I do not have 3D coding knowledge, I could not make the curved area, I transmit the codes I wrote below.

Example site : http://everpost.com

The sample on this site did not reach the same result as the documents I was looking at. When I tried with Panolens.js, I didn't get the same result. When I tried using the panoroma effect, I still did not get a good result.

Code:

```html
<script type="module">

/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.1/build/three.module.js';
const slideItems = [
'https://i.imgur.com/KjUybBD.png',
'https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/CwQSMv9.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/jg1dsZd.jpg',
].map(slideItemPath => { return {slideItemPath}; });

export default class Home {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      cameraRotationZ: 1.5,
      cameraRotationY: 0,
      cameraRotationYSpeed: 0.003,
    };
    this.initializePanaromicSlider();
  }

  initializePanaromicSlider() {
    // Scene And Camera Settings.
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000000);

    // Fish Eye Settings.
    this.camera.fov = 110;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    Object.keys(slideItems).forEach((key, index) => {
      const item = slideItems[index] || slideItems[key];
      const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(item.slideItemPath);

      const material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        map: texture,
      });

      const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions

      if (key % 2 === 0) {
        console.log('cift');
        sprite.position.y = 125;
      } else {
        console.log('tek');
        sprite.position.y = 0;
      }

      this.scene.add(sprite);
    });


    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Canvas Camera Position
    this.camera.position.z = this.state.cameraRotationZ;

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseControlAnimation.bind(this));

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      //   this.camera.rotation.x += 0.01;
      if (this.state.cameraRotationY < 0) {
        this.camera.rotation.y -= this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed;
      } else {
        this.camera.rotation.y += this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed;
      }

      renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };

    animate();
  }

  textureList() {

  }

  mouseControlAnimation(e) {
    this.event = e;
    this.wW = window.innerWidth;

    // Y Rotation
    if (this.event.clientX > (this.wW / 2)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationY = 1;
    } else {
      this.state.cameraRotationY = -1;
    }

    // Y Rotation Speed
    const quarterScreen = this.wW / 4;

    if (this.event.clientX < quarterScreen) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.005;
    } else if (this.event.clientX > quarterScreen && this.event.clientX < (quarterScreen * 2)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.003;
    } else if (this.event.clientX > (quarterScreen * 2) && this.event.clientX < (quarterScreen * 3)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.003;
    } else {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.005;
    }
  }
}

const home = new Home();

</script>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/building-an-images-gallery-using-pixijs-and-webgl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a curved plane by using a [`SphereBufferGeometry`](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-primitives.html#Diagram-SphereBufferGeometry) instead of a `Sprite`. `SphereBufferGeometry` takes a `phiStart` and `phiLength` for the area horizontally around the sphere as well as a `thetaStart` and `thetaLength` for the area vertically around the sphere

You can also use [`CylinderBufferGeometry`](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-primitives.html#Diagram-CylinderBufferGeometry) if you don't want them to curve vertically.

```html
<script type="module">

/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.1/build/three.module.js';
const slideItems = [
'https://i.imgur.com/KjUybBD.png',
'https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/CwQSMv9.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/v38pV.jpg',
'https://i.imgur.com/jg1dsZd.jpg',
].map(slideItemPath => { return {slideItemPath}; });

export default class Home {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      cameraRotationZ: 1.5,
      cameraRotationY: 0,
      cameraRotationYSpeed: 0.003,
    };
    this.initializePanaromicSlider();
  }

  initializePanaromicSlider() {
    // Scene And Camera Settings.
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);

    // Fish Eye Settings.
    this.camera.fov = 80;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    Object.keys(slideItems).forEach((key, index) => {
      const item = slideItems[index] || slideItems[key];
      const texture = loader.load(item.slideItemPath, (texture) => {
        // flip the texture since we're looking from inside the sphere
        texture.offset.x = 1;
        texture.repeat.x = -1;

        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: texture,
          side: THREE.BackSide,  
        });
        
        const phiStart = index * 0.6 + Math.PI;
        const phiLength = 0.5;
        const thetaLength = phiLength * texture.image.height / texture.image.width;    
        const thetaStart = Math.PI / 2 + ((index % 2) ? -thetaLength : 0);


        const geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(
           1,   // radius
           32,  // widthSegments
           16,  // heightSegments
           phiStart,
           phiLength,
           thetaStart,
           thetaLength);
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
        this.scene.add(mesh);
      });            
    });


    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseControlAnimation.bind(this));

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      //   this.camera.rotation.x += 0.01;
      if (this.state.cameraRotationY < 0) {
        this.camera.rotation.y -= this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed;
      } else {
        this.camera.rotation.y += this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed;
      }

      renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };

    animate();
  }

  textureList() {

  }

  mouseControlAnimation(e) {
    this.event = e;
    this.wW = window.innerWidth;

    // Y Rotation
    if (this.event.clientX > (this.wW / 2)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationY = 1;
    } else {
      this.state.cameraRotationY = -1;
    }

    // Y Rotation Speed
    const quarterScreen = this.wW / 4;

    if (this.event.clientX < quarterScreen) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.005;
    } else if (this.event.clientX > quarterScreen && this.event.clientX < (quarterScreen * 2)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.003;
    } else if (this.event.clientX > (quarterScreen * 2) && this.event.clientX < (quarterScreen * 3)) {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.003;
    } else {
      this.state.cameraRotationYSpeed = 0.005;
    }
  }
}

const home = new Home();

</script>
```